# How can I write an SQL query that does different things depending on the GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an orders ledger which shows some orders relating to a certain asset. The table contains the order updates of a certain order of a certain asset. I need to be able to get the total amount of each asset the user has by adding the amount_filled column of the different orders depending on if its a buy/sell. If it's the same order then we should get the most recent amount filled.

The table looks like this:

```
 asset_id | amount_filled | external_id | type 
----------+---------------+-------------+------
 asset1   |           101 | 20          | buy
 asset1   |            50 | 21          | sell
 asset2   |            30 | 23          | buy
 asset3   |            30 | 25          | buy
 asset3   |            30 | 25          | sell
 asset4   |            30 | 100         | buy
 asset4   |            50 | 100         | buy
```

Expected output is:

```
 asset_id | amount 
----------+--------
 asset2   |     30
 asset4   |     50
 asset1   |     51
 asset3   |     0
```

If the orders are different then the amount is buy amount - sell amount.

This was the only query I could get to work:

```
SELECT asset_id, sum(case when type = 'sell' 
    then amount_filled * -1 
    else amount_filled 
    end) as amount 
from (
    SELECT asset_id, type, max(amount_filled) as amount_filled
    from orders
    WHERE "orders"."user_id" = 'user-0' 
    group by asset_id, external_id, type
) f
group by asset_id;
```

I'm not 100% sure this query is correct, in any case I'm trying to optimize it, my idea is maybe to use a `DISTINCT ON` clause but I can't really get anything to work so far.

Comment: database rows don't have any natural ordering, so using the information provided there's no way for it to prefer 30 vs 50 using the information you've provided.  i.e. there's nothing there to know which is "the most recent"

Comment: @sammason Sorry forgot to mention that, theres a created_at column

Comment: In in any case, the max amount filled of an order should always be in the most recently added row which is why I used `max()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a99d246f3bae53c5803208d55da758a6)

You can use conditional aggregations, for example by using the `FILTER` clause:

```
SELECT
    asset_id,
    SUM(amount_filled) FILTER (WHERE type = 'buy')          -- 2
    - COALESCE(                                             -- 4
          SUM(amount_filled) FILTER (WHERE type = 'sell'),  -- 3
          0
      )
FROM  (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (asset_id, external_id, type)        -- 1
        *
    FROM mytable
    ORDER BY asset_id, external_id, type, created_at DESC
) s
GROUP BY asset_id
```

1. `DISTINCT ON` fetches the first record of an ordered group. You group is `(asset_id, external_id, type)` and it is ordered by the `created_at` column, in `DESC` order to get the most recent record to the top.
2. First sum the `buy` types
3. Then sum the `sell` types and subtract this from (1)
4. `COALESCE()` is to avoid subtracting a `NULL` value if no `sell` record is available

Comment: How does this group by `external_id`?

Comment: In your example output I cannot see the external_id, so why should it be grouped?

Comment: Your query is incorrect. Asset4 should be 50 not 80. If the external_id is the same, it should take the last amount_filled

Comment: Ok, what is the "last" record? Do you have a certain order criterion? An increasing id? Insert timestamp?

Comment: I have a created_at column

Comment: Extended answer

Comment: Why do you have `type` in the `distinct on` clause?

Comment: Seems like for about 700 rows, the query in my OP is 3x faster. Checked using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

Comment: Type is necessary because you need one sell and one buy record for the subtraction... Or how do you handle this?

Comment: Yes, performance is an issue for DISTINCT ON. This works only fast with appropriate indexes, otherwise you need to do many compare operations.